# Побитовое "или" и 0

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, в коде JS, после минификации (а может и нет) встречаются такие конструкции:

B = 0 | X

I = С * E | 0

A = 0 | Math.log2(с)

Для чего может использоваться побитовая операция ИЛИ с нулём?

Приведение к числу? Или что-то еще может означать

Comment: Всем спасибо. Это целочисленное деление

Comment: Не, это _приведение к целому 32х битному числу_